# Creating a button which takes you to another page

Tags: html

i want to create a button in html which will take me to another page

Comment: Do you want make button using hyperlink of tag or use form tag?

Comment: `<button onclick="window.location.href='nextpage.html'">Next</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using button onclick event:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title of the document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com/';">Click Here</button>
   </body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
<a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'><button>Link To freeCodeCamp</button></a>
```